# How to set a variable type but without giving it a value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

On and Angular 11 project using Typescript with Strict Mode I have:

```
export class AvatarComponent { 
  @Input() user: UserModel = null;
}
```

I am getting the compilation error:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.
```

Where `UserModel` is:

```
export class UserModel {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
}
```

How can I set `user` variable type to `UserModel` but with null value?

Comment: try `new UserModel()` the id and name would be null

Comment: Make the type `UserModel | null`?

Comment: By the way UserModel is a class not type. Yeahhh @R.Richards is correct though

Comment: What's wrong with just `@Input() user: UserModel;` - why would you need to set it explicitly to *null*, when by default it is *undefined*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you desire to set `null`:

```
export class AvatarComponent { 
  @Input() user: UserModel | null = null;
}
```

If you desire to set `undefined`:

```
export class AvatarComponent { 
  @Input() user: UserModel;
}
```

Comment: I tried to set it as undefined before but got the error "Property 'user' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.". I also added the constructor to class UserModel but didn't solve it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try @Input() user: UserModel = undefined;

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do

```
export class AvatarComponent { 
  @Input() user = <UserModel>null;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7f6obj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts